# Condition- assert using Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, assertions, browser-automation

[image]

I want to write a script which can detect this message " System is not responding to your request. Kindly try after sometime." as shown in the screenshot below. When this message comes up then I want verify and send mail to the development team.

Snippet which I wrote for verification purpose but it is not working fine for me, pls suggest some alternative:

```
String s1 = d1.findElementByXPath(".//*[@id='showSearchResultDiv']").getText();
        System.out.println(s1);
```

Comment: Please check whether div element is under a frame / iframe. And looking at your code it **seems** u r mistaking implicitlyWait with Thread.sleep...

Answer (score 1):

Remember to be careful when writing code for automation.  If the scenario doesn't always show up, you cannot try and find an XPath, because you can't getText() if the object (based on the XPath) doesn't exist first.  You probably need a try/catch around your code, and then put the println inside the try.  This scenario will occur quite frequently, so you may want to write your own framework on top of WebDriver to handle these use cases.

If that is not the issue.  Put a try/catch around the code that is failing to capture what the exception is.

Comment: <div id="showSearchResultDiv" style="margin: 0 auto; width: 960px;">
System is not responding to your request.Kindly try after some time.  
<link href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" rel="shortcut icon"/>
<meta content="deny" http-equiv="X-Frame-Options"/>
</div>

Comment: I got this snippet, but it does not work with webdriver try
     {
     assertTrue( d1.("System is not responding to your request.Kindly try after some time. "));
     System.out.println("results fail");
     }
     catch (Throwable e)
     {
     System.out.println("results pass");
     }

Comment: Does d1 exist?  Maybe it failed before it got to that line.  WebDriver sometimes crashes in it's own framework, so you might want to look at the internal exception.  I would try putting try/catch blocks further up the code, on the line when d1 is set or before.

Answer (score -1):

You should try to wait for your element to appear before examining its text:

```
for (int second = 0;; second++) {
    if (second >= 60) fail("timeout");
    try { if (d1.findElementByXPath(".//*[@id='showSearchResultDiv']").isDisplayed()) break; } catch (Exception e) {}
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
String s1 = d1.findElementByXPath(".//*[@id='showSearchResultDiv']").getText();
System.out.println(s1);
```

The exact code may be different, depending on the webpage you're testing (e.g. you should remove the 'fail' line if it's OK for the element not to appear every time.

Comment: try{
    String bodyText = d1.findElementByXPath(".//*[@id='showSearchResultDiv']").getText();
    if(bodyText.contains("System is not responding"))
    {System.out.println("fail");}
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {System.out.println(e);}   //is this fine

Comment: try{
    String bodyText = d1.findElementByXPath(".//*[@id='showSearchResultDiv']").getText();
    System.out.println("test2");
    System.out.println(bodyText.contains("System is not responding"));
    if(bodyText.contains("System is not responding"))
    
    {System.out.println("fail");
    System.out.println("test4");}
    System.out.println("test3");}
     
     catch(Exception e)
     {System.out.println(e);}

Comment: in this code:  System.out.println(bodyText.contains("System is not responding")); //status is fail